# How to trigger Oculus dash from unity script?

Tags: oculus, oculusgo

I am preparing my app for publishing to the Oculus store. There is a requirement that says "The app must open Oculus Dash if the user long-presses the back button."

How can I trigger dash? I searched through oculus documentation with no luck. Can anyone share the code snippet to trigger or invoke dash?

Comment: I thought this was a system feature, does it not work natively?

Comment: @Papooch for the oculus home button yes. But the requirement says long pressed back button.

Comment: I see, does any other app do this? If noone answers, I'd ask on SideQuest's Discord channel or try to leverage some open source project on there.